# Change DateTime to correspond user local after receiving data from Azure database

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have a service that is writing data into Azure database. However Azure automatically writes these "TimeStamps" in UTC. Due to I am not in UTC zone, my TimeStamps are not correct. After some investigations, I understood that there are several options. I am having hard times to understand which one should I use? Currently it is hard to see all possible problems that may appear in the future.

Here is my model:

```
  public class DataRecord : IDataRecord
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeNow { get; set; }
  }
```

So currently Azure don't care in which zone I am and just writes this DateTime time in UTC.

Possible options (I understood) I have:

1. Change DateTime into string and then parse back into DateTime on Client side
2. Add settings on Client side to select TimeZone, then do some math Azure DateTime + offset by selected TimeZone. If this solution, in which format should I create a list of time zones and how to perform calculations? My TimeStamp in UTC in DateTime format + ?
3. Retrieve clients time automatically, I have seen there are some JavaScript solutions available that are capable to get user browser time. For example: [Blazor Server Side: How can I read out the local time of the user/browser not of the server (using only c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63599853/blazor-server-side-how-can-i-read-out-the-local-time-of-the-user-browser-not-of)

My service, that is writing data into Database is in the same TimeZone as Client. Basically there is no need to do any calculations.

My project structure is following: Client, Server, Shared

Comment: You can also use relative time - "in 1h", or "3 days ago" - relative time doesn't care about time zones

Comment: IMHO always use `DateTimeOffset` to represent a time value with a time zone offset. `DateTime` barely works for the machine local timezone, and is completely useless for anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look on below steps to trigger your requirement.

> Change DateTime into string and then parse back into DateTime on Client side

Exactly agreed, You can do this way, like this and it's working as expected

**Azure Live Example:**

```
        var animal = await _context.Animals.FindAsync(id); // Getting Time From Azure 
        var azureTime = Convert.ToDateTime(animal!.AzureTime); // Because I have save date time as string
        var convertedToLocalTime = azureTime.ToLocalTime(); // Local Time
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** Here you might encounter one issue, if your server time is not same as your local time in that case time conversion may not be as
expected. So if that is the case you could have a try in following way:

**Convert Azure Time To Any Standard Time:**

This the way you could convert UTC time to any standard time zone. Here is the example:

```
        var azureTime = "18-Apr-22 5:21:29 AM"; // Getting Time From Azure 
        var convertedAzureTime = Convert.ToDateTime(azureTime); // Because I have save date time as string
        TimeZoneInfo gmtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
        DateTime yourLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(convertedAzureTime, gmtZone);
        Console.WriteLine("Azure Time {0}",convertedAzureTime);
        Console.WriteLine("Converted Local Time {0}",yourLocalTime);
```

**Note:** You can convert in anytime zone you want by using [`FindSystemTimeZoneById`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid?view=net-6.0). You can check the [dotnetfiddle example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KIGWti)

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Storing dates in UTC is desirable as it is a standardised base from which the time in any other zone can easily be calculated using the Microsoft DateTime methods.

When saving data, if you are creating the timestamp in code then use:

```
DateTime myDateTimeToStore = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

If the data is entered by a user (using their local time zone) then capture the input into a DateTime and then convert to UTC:

```
DateTime localDateTimeInputByUser;

DateTime utcDateTime = localDateTimeInputByUser.ToUniversalTime();
```

Once converted to Utc you can store in the database.

Then, when retrieving, you can convert it back to local time, using:

```
DateTime utcDateTimeFromDatabase;

DateTime localDateTime = utcDateTimeFromDatabase.ToLocalTime();
```

For more complex scenarios, you can convert between time zones without doing your own maths:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones